# git lfs handling of duplicated files in a repo using pointer files

Tags: windows, git, git-lfs

I have to duplicate a file (same name, same content) that is handled by git lfs twice inside a repo in different directories for our 3rd party software to work properly. This is a limitation to the 3rd party software that I have to live with.

- ./directory1/large_file.crg
- ./directory2/large_file.crg

git lfs intelligently identifies that they are the same file, and only downloads it once to a local repo. The other files simply get a pointer to the location of the real file. This is causing problems with the 3rd party software as it can not read the pointer.

Is there any way I can force Git LFS to duplicate the file instead of point to it?
Or can someone please point to me where this behavior is documented so I can explain it to colleagues?

Comment: Just to be clear, when you added these two files to the repo, the full file was there twice, but when you clone is back out, you get a pointer instead? That sounds like a bug to me! A clone should always be just like the original.

Comment: Now, can you specify your OS, in case the behaviour is OS specific?

Comment: woah I did not even consider to check if it's OS specific. I was seeing this strange behavior in Windows, but on Linux, it duplicates the full files as I expected originally.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does Linux duplicate the file, or create a hard link? (Run `ls -i` on each to see the inode. If the two files have the same inode, they're hard links to each other, i.e., there's only one file on the file system, with two separate directory entries pointing to them.) Windows does not support hard links... when you say you get a "pointer", can you be more precise about what kind of pointer? Is this a Windows-specific soft link kind of object?

Comment: This is getting more interesting.
The two files have different inode numbers. After I dug deeper into the linux file system (I rarely use the linux clone), one of the files is of type 'Link to plan text document', while the other is of type 'plain text document'. The file with the Link type is the file that gets a pointer file in Windows.

The file I refer to as pointer file in Windows is simply a text file that has 1 line "../directory1/large_file.crg" which is the relative path to the fully downloaded file.

Comment: OK, then I have a new theory: you original repo probably never contained two copies of the file in the first place. It was created on Linux, with the big file in one directory, and symlink to it in the other. Git is perfectly capable of storing symlinks. When you check them back out on Linux, they work perfectly. But when you check them back out on Windows, you get what you're seeing.

Comment: You're not going to like the solution: symlinks are just not compatible between OSs, so if you have a repo that is meant to be use on both Linux and Windows, don't use symlinks. So I would do `git rm <symlink version of the file>`, duplicate the big file, `git add <copied version of the file>`. Git will be smart enough to reuse the same blob for both, but you'll have two copies in each clone.

Comment: Bingo! This repo is so old and everyone is gone already so I don't really know how it originated but it makes so much sense that it originated in Linux. Will this double my git lfs usage? I am capped at 10GB due to company policy.

Comment: The same blob should be reused in your Git LFS storage too, so no, I'm quite sure it won't double your git lfs usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

Don't use symlinks in repos that are meant to be used on both Windows and Linux/Mac.

### The problem with symlinks

Based on the comments under the question, it turns out the repo did not have two copies of the big file, but rather one copy, and a Linux-style symlink pointing to it.

Git fully supports symlinks - you can add them, modify them, check them in, check them back out. As long as you're staying in Linux, everything will work fine.

But Windows* does not (always) support Linux-style symlinks, so what you get is broken, as you describe in the comments under the question.

### The solution: get rid of symlinks in cross-platform repos

It might not seem like a nice solution, but if your repo is meant to be used on Windows and *nix OSs, avoid symlinks.

You will still save some space, at least on the Git server, and in Git LFS storage too, because Git is smart enough to reuse the same blob when there are two identical files in a repo. In fact, it's unable to do anything else, because the sha1 hash of the blob is what is used to store and retrieve the blob! You'll just have two copies of it in each sandbox that uses that repo.

### The asterisk: Windows does support symlinks, just not by default...

Kudos to @GianMarco for this blog post link: [Symlinks in Windows 10](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/)

Windows can now support symlinks, but it's not enabled by default: you have to be an admin or have the developer mode enabled.

Here's essential reading if you want to use symlinks with Git on Windows: [Git-for-Windows's Symbolic Links documentation](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/Symbolic-Links).

TL;DR: if you configure Git-for-Windows to try to create symlinks (with `git config core.symlinks true`) and you have permission to create them, you should be able to checkout a repo with symlinks and see them work correctly on Windows too.

I personally remain averse to using symlinks in cross-platform repos, because I want my repos to always just work as intended, but I'm happy to see the option now exists on Windows!

Comment: Windows support symlinks: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/

Comment: @GianMarco Thank you for that pointer! I did some tests and was annoyed to see symlinks didn't work by default as a regular user and I wrote up a bunch of comments here earlier. But I figured out how to make them work now, so I updated my answer with the information.